# Sendmail How to stop email delievery to outside emails

Tags: configuration, sendmail, centos6

I have setup local development server which has CentOS. While working with project if I have actual data and our code has email notification functionality, then email gets sends to actual email address. I want that Sendmail should only deliever emails to local recipients and not the external emails like @gmail.com, @yahoo.com or anyother.

What configuration I should change in sendmail module config to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Sendmail: Catch all outgoing emails

You may define relay for outgoing email to redirect them to specified local mailbox.

`sendmail.mc` file modification [`sendmail.mc` must be recompiled into `sendmail.cf`]:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`local:cactchall')
```

`aliases` file [aliases file must be recompiled using newaliases command]

```
cactchall: local_account_name
```

It is possible to configure sendmail to reject such message using `error` mailer instead of `local` mailer in smart host definition.